# String variable in filename being truncated

Tags: python, pandas

I create CSV files with a string in the file name:

```
df.to_csv('output/' + some_info + '.csv', index=False)
```

If the filename is too long, it will truncate it with "..." making it exactly 50 characters long.

Is there a way to have the entire contents of the some_info variable in the filename?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the ...?

Comment: The last 3 characters of whatever is contained in some_info.  I just tried setting pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1) and it worked! Someone posted the answers here but quickly deleted it for some reason.

Comment: Please show the code used to display the file name (in the question itself). The thing is that your question implies that you are seeing this in the file system, not in the python shell.